# How to control Azure DevOps automatically updated node

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have a few doubts on Azure pipeline. we developed a react application with node version 16 and we publish our application with azure but Azure automatically updated node version to 18. Our build not worked then we downgrade to node version 16 at Azure. Now my doubts is.

1. I manually changed node version 16 in Azure pipeline. In future does it will change automatically again?
2. If it changed means, what is the permanent solution for it?
3. If I change node version to latest in application means, does it provide any new issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the Node version to be used in the pipeline by adding the installation as a step like so:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '16.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm build'
```

The versionSpec file holds the version you wish to install and use. If you add this to your yaml file, then the build will use the same Node version consistently.